# Как сделать placeholder'ы под картинки при их загрузке на странице

Tags: javascript, html

Такой стиль загрузки я заметил на сайте [https://unsplash.com/(Наверное](https://unsplash.com/(%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) всем известен ) 
Помогите пожалуйста , буду ждать ответа 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изначально там backgroud: gradient, по загрузке появляется background-image, а размер указан в пикселях

Comment: я не понял ничего честное слово

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вам стоит написать свой html/css код и вставить его в свой вопрос, чтобы отвечающий смог просто взять его и доработать его под ваши нужды, а не делать работу за вас, по увиденной вами картинке. Всего вам доброго.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov какой код вы ожидаете, если автор даже примерно не знает, как реализуется подобная функция?

Comment: @andreymal Здравствуйте. Вопрос у автора именно про стиль загрузки, ничего не мешает сделать сетку с фотографиями как на картинке. Я не думаю, что человек который не знает даже базовый HTML/CSS, будет задавать такие вопросы. Я ожидаю увидеть в коде разметку и базовые стили, т.е. все то, что на картинке, но с обычной загрузкой.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov вопрос вообще не про сетку. Не требуйте того, что совершенно не требуется.

Comment: @andreymal `Не требуйте того, что совершенно не требуется` - удивительное заявление. Ведь даже здесь, автор вопроса уже сам ответил и вот, в его ответе присутствует HTML и CSS код. А я что попросил? - верно разметку(HTML-код) и стили(CSS-код). Даже сам автор отвечая, все это написал и даже видя это, вы говорите мне, чтобы я не требовал HTML и CSS код. Не могу я найти слов, чтобы объяснить, что в верстке необходима разметка и стили, вот даже автор вопроса решил, что здесь это необходимо, возможно ему поверите...

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov разметку чего? Сетки? Вопрос не про сетку, она здесь не нужна. Стили чего? Сетки? Ещё раз, вопрос не про сетку, она здесь не нужна. Автор не спрашивает про сетку — автор спрашивает про картинку. И что остаётся — скопировать единственный тег img из ближайшего учебника? Но зачем? Какой в этом смысл? Или у вас руки отсохнут написать в ответе тег img самостоятельно?

Answer (score 0):

Кому интересно нашлось решение , высота placeholder'а формируется из css свойства
padding-bottom , потом к этому свойству подставляется высота картинки , она берется(возможно) из бд , у них на сайте это свойство рассчитывается  в процентах 
(высота картинки * 100%)/ширину картинки(или ширину контейнера если она совпадает с шириной картинки) , но что бы картинка не занимала все окно , нужно ее обернуть в контейнер  , 
вообщем код ниже .
Смысл всего этого просто показать плашки(означает что в них что-то должно быть) когда картинка загружается .

```css
.container{
  width: 450px;
 }
  .box{
   background-color: #444;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
  }
  img{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" style="padding-bottom: высота картинки * 100%)/ширину картинки % ">
  <img  src="img/1.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: На самом деле достаточно прописать `background-color` для картинки, не забыв указать её размеры в пикселях. Контейнеры и паддинги здесь совсем не для этого.

Comment: Просто мне  не хотелось , почему-то, указывать размеры для картинки в тегах или в CSS

Comment: Всем спасибо за попытку найти ответ )